# Generating PDF files the way browsers "print to PDF"

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf

I've tried a few libraries to generate PDFs and they seem to fall short or are work intensive.

DOMPDF doesn't support modern CSS, doesn't load Bootstrap, and takes a while to generate large files.

The wkhtmltopdf libraries produce gigantic files and you can't search/copy text.

How do the browsers do it? Chrome's "Print to PDF" is perfect. I just need a button to generate the PDF exactly as it's rendered in the browser and save it to the server without writing specific code to generate/style the PDF.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer ?